# How to make a FakeItEasy faked object's method throw on first invocation and return on second?

Tags: c#, exception, mocking, moq, fakeiteasy

I have a method which is invoked multiple times within a `foreach` loop, each time with the same parameter values.

```
foreach (var item in myCollection)
{
    // do some stuff with item
    // then...
    var result = _myService.Foo(aConstant, anotherConstant);
    // do something with result
}
```

I am trying to write a test that ensures the loop continues iterating even if `_myService.Foo()` throws an exception on the first time through.

In [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), I am allowed to chain together calls to `Returns` and `Throws` like so:

```
mockService.Setup(x => x.Foo(aConstant, anotherConstant)).Throws<Exception>().Returns(someResult);
```

This will cause the call to `Foo` to throw an Exception but all subsequent calls will return `someResult`. My main goal is to ensure that a try/catch block is wrapped around the second half of code inside my foreach block so that the loop continues even if an Exception occurs.

```
foreach (var item in myCollection)
{
    // do some stuff with item
    // then...
    try
    {
        var result = _myService.Foo(aConstant, anotherConstant);
        // do something with result
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ignore any exceptions here and continue looping
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish something similar to this in [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy)?  Or is there a different (better) strategy I could use for doing this kind of assertion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can now chain configurations using 'Then'. You can read more about it in the FakeItEasy documentation for [changing behavior between calls](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing-behavior-between-calls/).

This is an example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Do();
}

[Test]
public void ThrowsFirstTime()
{
    var fakeFoo = A.Fake<IFoo>();
    A.CallTo(() => fakeFoo.Do()).Throws<Exception>().Once().Then.Returns(1);

    Assert.Throws<Exception>(()=>fakeFoo.Do());
    int t = fakeFoo.Do();

    A.CallTo(() => fakeFoo.Do()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Twice);
    Assert.That(t, Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Comment: This works exactly as expected. I also tried your example, changing it to call `Do()` a few more times to make sure it doesn't throw an Exception again after the first time, but it doesn't, as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else…

I figured out a way to do this for methods with `void` return type. I used the `Invokes()` method:

```
A.CallTo(() => _fakeService.VoidMethod(aConstant, anotherConstant))
                           .Invokes(ThrowExceptionOnFirstInvocation);
```

Then outside the Test method, I defined the `ThrowExceptionOnFirstInvocation` function:

```
private void ThrowExceptionOnFirstInvocation(IFakeObjectCall obj)
{
    if (_numInvocations++ == 0) throw new Exception();
}

private int _numInvocations;
```

I am still not sure how to do this for a method which returns something though.